# array populated from a loop gets overwritten

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, loops, overriding

I have the following code - I am parsing a dataframe and creating lists from subsets of data found in the dataframe. I then transform the lists into arrays as I'd like to do further treatment (later in my code), to the final array generated at the end of each iteration of the loop.

My issue is the following: I would like a copy of the array (ivxl_arr) to be placed into a new dataframe (newdf) for each iteration of the loop (each iteration should populate ivxl_arr with different sets of data). As of now, the array (ivxl_arr) keeps getting overwritten over and over for each iteration of the loop. When I print the array, it prints the corresponding batch of data for each iteration which is what I need, but when trying to place into a df a copy of ivxl_arr, I get only one array sent to the new dataframe instead of "m" arrays. Does anyone have a suggestion by chance? I have been trying for a while and can't seem to figure out a solution. Many thanks!

```
for m in range(len(mats)):
    xx_ = [] #list to feed into an array for further treatment later in my code
    delt_ = [] #list to feed into an array for further treatment later in my code

    for i in range(len(df)):   
        if df['Maturity'][i] == mats[m]:
            d = df['IVX'][i]
            xx_.append(d)
            di = df['raw_dlt'][i]
            delt_.append(di)
        
        
            ivxl_arr = np.asarray(xx_)      
            delta_arr = np.asarray(delt_)

     print(ivxl_arr)
     newdf = pd.DataFrame(ivol_arr)

''' expected data from each iteration of the array I'd like in 4 separate columns of newdf :
[84.5306 83.6606 82.8445 82.1378 81.5821 80.6491 79.8861 78.9784 79.0328]
[77.8581 75.4054 73.6177 72.3086 71.2534 70.1216 68.8867 67.3913 63.5827]
[65.8867 62.7784 60.1962 57.9742 56.2001 54.9078 52.6097 50.806  47.3156]
[62.0567 57.322  54.918  52.9547 51.4354 49.6318 48.0504 45.1384 42.5164]
```

Comment: Could you show how you put `ivxl_arr` into `df`?

Comment: yep I added this. Thanks for your help. Let me know if I need to add more context to the code....I feel like this is not very clear without the rest...

Comment: The line `newdf = pd.DataFrame(ivol_arr)` is inside the for loop, as a result, in each loop iteration, one `newdf` variable is created, and filled with `ivxl_arr` of the iteration. To fix this, `newdf` should be created outside the for loop, and in each loop iteration, add `ivxl_arr` into `newdf`.

Comment: Thanks, I took "newdf = pd.DataFrame(ivol_arr)" outside of the loop, but how do you append "ivxl_arr" from each iteration to "newdf" if it is outside of the loop?

Comment: Try `newdf[m] = ivxl_arr`, which puts `ivxl_arr` in the `m` key of the dataframe.

Comment: One more question... now that I can fill each column with data, is there a way to label the column header within the loop? I tried newerdf.columns = mats[m], does not work. The mats list contains the header I need.

Comment: Suppose your DataFrame has columns `Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')` (the column names are integer numbers), then you could rename the columns with the `rename` method, like this: `newerdf.rename(columns={0: "zero", 1: "some name", 2: "other name"}, inplace=True)`.

Comment: I suggest you write an answer for your question of "*array gets overwritten*", maybe it would help you improve your understanding.